# Explanation on why a constructor cannot be virtual based on study : Correct the mistakes if any

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding

I did some study to find out why a constructor cannot be virtual. I am consolidating my understanding here.

I will first explain what is a virtual function and then explain why a constructor cannot be virtual based on the first explanation.

**What is a `virtual function` ?**

> A virtual function is a function or a method in the base class which
>   can be redefined or overriden in the derived class, by a function with
>   the same signature. In other words, virtual function allows to have a
>   customized implementation of the base class method in the derived
>   class. It needs to be declared with the `virtual` keyword. At the time
>   of virtual function invocation, the decision to choose which version
>   of the function definition(in the base class or derived class) is made at
>   run-time, depending on the type of the invoking object(dynamic
>   binding).
>
> When a function is declared virtual, it tells the compiler that the
>   type of the object which would invoke the virtual function should be
>   determined only during run-time. Then based on the type of the object,
>   the function call should be bound to the function definition and the
>   appropriate function should be invoked.

**Why a `constructor` cannot be virtual?**

> When a function is declared virtual, it tells the compiler that the
>   type of the object which would invoke the function should be
>   determined only during run-time, and then invoke the appropriate
>   version of the function based on the type of the object.
>
> If the constructor were to be declared virtual, it would tell the
>   compiler that type of object which would invoke the constructor should
>   be determined at run-time. But for constructing an object, the exact
>   type of object should be known at compile time rather than at run-time.
>   This is the reason why a constructor cannot be virtual.

I would like the SO members to correct the mistakes in both the answers, if any. I think it would help me and others, if you could correct the answers by re-writing it as your answers, rather than just pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A constructor cannot be virtual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506938/a-constructor-cannot-be-virtual)

Comment: Please dont close down this question. It happened to have the same heading as a previous question. But the need is different.

Comment: I have modified the heading of the question. It is not a duplicate. It just happened to have the same heading as a previous question